# When removing dynamically created objects in Objective-C, what should I set to nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, uiview, null

Easy question alert, but I want to be sure I'm not being stupid.

In my iPad app I'm dynamically creating a UIView, and filling it with UIButtons, UIImageViews, sometimes a MPMoviePlayerController, sometimes a UIImageView with a few UIImages as an animation.

After a certain amount of time, I'm removing the view from the screen and discarding it.

The question is:  **should I be setting any of these objects to nil?**

I'm releasing everything after I allocate it, and I'm not getting any leaks.  BUT my app is eventually crashing after running out of memory.  Each one of these views I build seems to be lurking somewhere in memory.

Any help, much appreciated.

Duncs

Comment: add breakpoints to classes dealloc method and check. is they are really deallocated when you supposed?

Comment: This is all running inside a UIViewController so there is no dealloc method called (until the user closes the UIViewController, but the app crashes before this happens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to comment without code or knowing if you are using ARC or not (guessing not, because you said "releasing").

1. Do an Analyze and fix every problem it flags.  It's very good at telling you if you are retain/releasing correctly
2. Use the Leaks Instrument to find leaks
3. If you have no more leaks, but are still crashing, then turn on Zombies and make sure you aren't releasing anything too early

Setting a variable to nil doesn't do anything to release the memory.  If you have a `@property` that is declared with `(retain)`, the auto-generated setter will make it so  setting the property to nil will release the old value.

The `dealloc` of any class that has properties needs to do this to all properties that are pointers to retained objects.  For UIViewControllers, you would also want to do this in `viewDidUnload` for IBOutlet properties.

Comment: Thanks Lou. No ARC, no leaks, no zombies.  And none of my dynamic objects are @properties.  I'll do an analyze now and see if that brings anything up - but I'll accept your answer since you've explained that I don't need to set anything to nil.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using ARC, while you add the `UIView` as subview of another `UIView`, the retain count will increase. On you "removeFromSuperview" it, it will decrease and it will be deallocated. In a Non-Arc environment, after allocating it and adding it to a UIView the retain will be of 2, but then you release it, so it will go back to 1. So there is always a balance between those. To check what's going on, **you should use Instruments**, to pinpoint the problem.

---

It only makes sense to "nil" it is when you have a @property of the iVar (for retain). Why is that? Because it will release the old value and it will set the new one to the value passed (in this case nil). You probably think that the issue is related the `UIViews` but might be something else. That's why I advise you to use Instruments.

Comment: Thanks Jacky Boy.  I'm not using ARC and I'm releasing everything.  The question is:  should I be setting anything to nil?  Do I need to set the UIImageViews to nil or the UIImages inside the UIImageViews to nil?  Or will my releases handle all of that for me?

Comment: Thanks mate.  When I use instruments I'm not getting any leaks, but my total allocations is constantly rising.

Comment: You don't need to use leaks... Use "allocations" and see what kind of objects is going towards the sky...